# My question does not have a "bounty" button

Tags: support, bounty

[image]

As you can see from my picture, I cannot put my question into a bounty although I have more than 50 reputation and the question has been posted for more than 2 days.

I only have two bounties so far where one of them has already expired. I know three bounties are the maximum number for bounty and I do not even violate this at all.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation. You need 75 reputation to start bounties.

Comment: You know you need 75 total rep to start a bounty, right? https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties Once you have that rep, the "start a bounty" option will appear _under_ the comments. (Under the "add a comment" button, to be specific. It's easy to miss, same font and colored black.)

Comment: The instruction says 50 which I used to use before for my previous bounties. So the instruction in the stackexhange is wrong?

Comment: The 50 is the minimum you can set for a bounty- But you need at least 75 to even have the option.

Comment: Ok. That was not so clear in the instruction. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: From the https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties page: "set bounties, Privilege type: Creation privilege, Awarded at: 75 reputation"